# Application of Fatou's Lemma

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n \geq 0$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions on $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ a.e. on $(a,b)$. 
Let $F(x) = \int_a^x f(y)dy$ and $F_n(x) = \int_a^x f_n(y)dy$, where $x \in [a,b]$.

Show $\int_a^b \left[f(x)+F(x)\right]dx \leq \liminf \int_a^b \left[f_n(x)+F_n(x)\right]dx$.

My attempt:

Define $g_n(x) = f_n(x) + F_n(x)$. By Fatou's Lemma, $\int_a^b \liminf g_n \leq \liminf \int_a^b\left[f_n(x)+F_n(x)\right]dx$. Since $f_n \to f$, $\liminf f_n = f$. However, I'm stuck on showing that $F_n \to F$. This seems like a situation where dominated convergence would be useful, but how would I bound the sequence $(f_n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply Fatou's lemma twice:

$$F(x) = \int_a^x \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(y) \, dy \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_a^x f_n(y) \, dy = \liminf_{n \to \infty} F_n(x)$$

and so

$$\int_a^b (f(x)+F(x)) \, dx \leq \int_a^b \liminf_{n \to \infty} (f_n(x)+F_n(x)) \, dx \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b (f_n(x)+F_n(x)) \, dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote $(a,b)=X$. Then here you have $f_n\ge0$ and $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e. hence by Fatous lemma $$\int\limits_{X}f(x) dx\le \liminf_n\int\limits_{X}f_n(x) dx$$ Now $f_n(y)\chi_{(a,x)}\rightarrow f(y)\chi_{(a,x)}$ a.e. hence one can again apply fatous lemma to get that $$F(x)=\int\limits_{a}^{x}f(y)dy\le\liminf_n\int\limits_{a}^{x}f_n(y)dy=\liminf_n F_n(x)$$ and since they all are positive once again applying fatous lemma to get that $$\int\limits_X F(x)dx\le \int\limits_{X}\liminf_n F_n(x)dx\le \liminf_n\int\limits_{X}F_n(x)dx$$ and hence now your result follows.